# What to close when using Java sockets

Tags: java, sockets

So I have this class that uses Java sockets:

```java
public class Connection {
    private final Socket socket;

    private final PrintWriter out;
    private final BufferedReader in;

    private final ObjectOutputStream objectOut;
    private final ObjectInputStream objectIn;

    public Connection(Socket socket) throws IOException {
        this.socket = socket;
        this.out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        this.objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        this.objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    }

    public void close() throws IOException {
        socket.close();
        out.close();
        in.close();
        objectOut.close();
        objectIn.close();
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return socket.getInetAddress() + ":" + socket.getPort();
    }
}
```

In the method close, what do I really need to close and what is going to be closed when socket.close() is called?

Comment: First close streams (they can buffer data and closing them flushes data) and do `socket.close()` as the last one.

Comment: According to the javadocs on Socket's close method (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close()]) it states: "Closing this socket will also close the socket's InputStream and OutputStream" so I guess you wil be ok!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let me set 2 alarma about Object Streams...

1. ObjectOutputStream would send some bytes that would need to be flushed, while ObjectInputStream expect some bytes to read in order to finish. It's fairly easy to hang when using object streams over sockets.
2. Object streams have a memory of objects they already sent, by design. If you don't outputstream.reset() then the server's and client's memory will grow indefinitely.

Now, closing streams append TCP FIN on the corresponding stream (basically flush and end). That's to do half-closed sockets. If you socket.close() before stream close(), it would send a TCP RST which is a harsh disconnect and the peer may not get all the bytes, and may also experience a "broken pipe" if attempting to write on its not yet closed outputstream.